# Installing programs on Ubuntu Live

Tags: live-usb

Is there possibly a way of installing a program on Ubuntu Live (on USB) and the have it there like a all preinstalled programs (such as Open Office)?

If it were possible, it'd be so great!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can have a persistent partition on your usb stick that will keep all your changes and programs you install.
Here is the more info on [Persistence](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD/Persistence)

Answer (score 0):

I think yes a lot of program can do that unless those need to reboot like vga driver or new kernel but anything yes and we can use live distro to test this distro on our system and use it for rescue too